# All Pages and Post are redirecting to 404 Not Found in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, apache2, custom-error-pages

I am using wordpress, I have created 3 pages and 4 posts on my website. I am able to access the front page but the rest of the pages are showing 404 not found, Same for post also.

If I use some logic to fetch the pages or post then I am getting it but when I click on the view button it's showing

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at *.*.*.* Port 80 // I have hide the IP here
```

Would you help me out what is the issue with my code?

Below is the code that I am using in htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# secure spesific files
<Files a_secret_file.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>
```

The below is the code that I have in /etc/apache2/apche2.conf

```
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have noticed that if I select the Permalink Settings plain option then all the pages are working.

Comment: U need to flush your permalinks follow this instructions [link](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/)

Comment: @wazidshah, I have tried this so many times but still have the same issue

Comment: @wazidshah, the Plain URL is working but if I select the Post name URL  then it's redirecting to 404 Not Found.